# Many to many vs one row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm interested how and why many to many relationship is better than storing the information in one row.

Example: I have two tables, Users and Movies (very big data). I need to establish a relationship "view".
I have two ideas:

1. Make another column in Users table called "views", where I will store the ids of the movies this user has viewed, in a string. for example: "2,5,7...". Then I will process this information in PHP.
2. Make new table users_movies (many to many), with columns user_id and movie_id. row with user_id=5 and movie_id=7 means that user 5 has viewed movie 7.

I'm interested which of this methods is better and WHY. Please consider that the data is quite big.

Comment: Imagine this: what if you want to create a list of users who have seen a specific movie, or simply count how much users have seen that movie? You'd have to fetch all the data, then loop through it to filter the users that have seen that movie. Especially since you will have much data, this will not be very efficient. This is why relational databases have been invented.

Comment: method one is like trying to "unsqlize" an sql database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second method is better in just about every way. Not only will you utilize your DBs indexes to find records faster, it will make modification far far easier.

Answer (score 1):

Approach 1) could answer the question "Which movies has User X viewed" by just having an SQL like "`...field_in_set(movie_id, user_movielist) ...`". But the other way round ("Which user do have viewed movie x") won't work on an sql basis.

That's why I always would go for approach 2): clear normalized structure, both ways are simple joins.

Answer (score 0):

It's just about the needs you have. If you need performance then you must accept redundancy of the information and add a column. If your main goal is to respect the Normalization paradigma then you should not have redundancy at all.
When I have to do this type of choice I try to estimate the space loss of redundancy vs the frequency of the query of interest and its performance.

Answer (score 0):

A few more thoughts.

In your first situation if you look up a particular user you can easily get the list of ids for the films they have seen. But then would need a separate query to get the details such as the titles of those movies. This might be one query using IN with the list of ids, or one query per film id. This would be inefficient and clunky.

With MySQL there is a possible fudge to join in this situation using the FIND_IN_SET() function (although a down side of this is you are straying in to non standard SQL). You could join your table of films to the users using ON FIND_IN_SET(film.id, users.film_id) > 0 . However this is not going to use an index for the join, and involves a function (which while quick for what it does, will be slow when performed on thousands of rows).

If you wanted to find all the users who had view any film a particular user had viewed then it is a bit more difficult. You can't just use FIND_IN_SET as it requires a single string and a comma separated list. As a single query you would need to join the particular user to the film table to get a lot of intermediate rows, and then join that back against the users again (using FIND_IN_SET) to find the other users.

There are ways in SQL to split up a comma separated list of values, but they are messy and anyone who has to maintain such code will hate it!

These are all fudges. With the 2nd solution these easy to do, and any resulting joins can easily use indexes (and possibly the whole queries can just use indexes without touching the actual data).

A further issue with the first solution is data integretity. You will have to manually check that a film doesn't appear twice for a user (with the 2nd solution this can easily be enforced using a unique key). You also cannot just add a foreign key to ensure that any film id for a user does actually exist. Further you will have to manually ensure that nothing enters a character string in your delimited list of ids.